# How do I get the value of a tag in the aws cli describe-instances output?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I want to get the instance id and the value of the name tag, this doesn't work:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=InstaneNameTagPrefix*' --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{InstanceId:InstanceId,Tags:Tags.Key=Name}'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After going [this](http://jmespath.org/examples.html#working-with-nested-data) through JMESPath example, I was able to make it working. Try this and let me know how it goes at your end.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=myDevEC2*' --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].{InstanceId:InstanceId,Tags:Tags[?Key == `Name`] | [0].Value}'
```

Output -

```
[
    [
        {
            "InstanceId": "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "Tags": "myDevEC2-123"
        }
    ]
]
```

Since `Tags` is an array, you will need to filter to just Name pair. After that pipe the Tags result and select `Value`.

PS - You might want to rename JSON output second element to `InstanceName` instead `Tags` :)

Comment: My hero... I'm learning new capabilities of this CLI everyday. It's so flexible.

Comment: @Imran: when I tried above provided CLI command it returns the output correctly but when I tried the same cli command in groovy script.. I get no output

Comment: @codenamebazinga odd. not sure how you are executing the command in groovy. You could post the question under groovy tag to get reviewed by language experts.

Comment: @Imran I have posted the question along with the stderror from Groovy script . Seems It is unable to comprehend backtick in the groovy script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73419967/groovy-script-returns-empty-list-for-aws-ec2-describe-instances#comment129698067_73419967