# how to get the value of a specific TAG for a vpc via aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Is it possible to get a specific TAG value for a vpc?

```
key | value
alpha | hello
```

for example is it possible to directly get the TAG value for key `aplha`?

The indirect method is to use `ws ec2 describe-vpcs --vpc-id vpc-...` and then parse for Tags.alpha, but is there a shorter method.

I see a similar method for EC2 in [How do I get the value of a tag in the aws cli describe-instances output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047510/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-a-tag-in-the-aws-cli-describe-instances-output)

Answer (score 0):

There must be better ways to do this but for your case I would do
`aws ec2 describe-vpcs --vpc-ids vpc-abcd3456 --region $your-region --query Vpcs[0].Tags[0].alpha`

Comment: this was close and helped me refine `--query`, it, I ended up with `--query "Vpcs[0].Tags[?Key == 'alpha'].Value" to get the Value="hello"